# Can timing attacks over a webservice be eliminated by standardizing the time it takes to return a request?

Tags: web-service, timing-attack

For example, would this (pseudo)-code work?

```
let t = timeRightNow()
let message = stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()
waitUntilTime(t+1 second)
send message
```

Or similar? That way the time that the message is sent doesn't depend on the timing of `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()`.

Would an attacker still be able to determine how long `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()` took to run?

Comment: Can I as the attacker launch something like a DOS attack.  My goal is to slow down your system so that `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked` will take more than one second.  Perhaps you could add a condition that if the process takes more than one second it errors rather than sending a message.

Comment: @emory I was thinking that would be a problem. Probably would be an error message.

Comment: I think even with the error message, there is a timing issue.  As an attacker, I will launch a DOS style attack until 50% of computations error.  Then small changes in timing may mean the difference between result (time <= 1 second) and error (time > 1 second).  I will collect large amounts of data and calculate averages.

Comment: @emory Maybe after the first failure, the whole service goes down (can't get much info from a single failure). Or you just hope that attackers can't DOS. Or both.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `t + s` is sufficient to cover any delays in responses introduced by a DDoS style attack, where `s` is the number of seconds.

That is, hitting a service listener that calls the above in order to encourage `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()` to take longer than `s` could reveal to the attacker how long, on average, `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()` takes to execute, once the `t + s` barrier is broken.

To mitigate this, you could mask this extra time by detecting when your function takes longer:

```
let t = timeRightNow()
let s = 1
let waitTime = t + s
let message = stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()
let executeTime = timeRightNow() - t

if timeRightNow() > waitTime
  waitUntilTime(timeRightNow() + executeTime * csprng(2,1)) # Random wait of between 1 and 2 times the original execution time (integer)
else
  waitUntilTime(waitTime)
send message
```

Note though, [with enough requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406531/413180) it might be possible to get an average that will even out, leaking the time taken to execute `stuffWhoseTimingCantBeLeaked()`.

With higher values of `s`, the risk can be lowered further, at the expense of performance. You could also introduce detection of whether your web service is requested repeatedly from a certain user or IP address and then rate limit the connection.